# AngularJS does not see selected option when options set changed via jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

There is an AngularJS (v1. 4. 14) app (legacy code) and a web form which has this select tag:

```
<select id="selectCourses" class="input-select" data-ng-model="fields.course" data-courses="form.courses"></select>
```

Options are added to it using the AnglarJS directive *courses* from the JSON *form.courses* object. Inside this directive jQuery (v3.2.1) is used which first clears the old options and then appends new options to the selector. In the options specific courses grouped by categories (labels) - see the directive code below. Unfortunately *ng-options* or *ng-repeat* is not used here.

The *jQuery Form Styler plugin* and *Bootstrap 3* are also used in the design of the drop-down list.

The optionslist depends on two radio-inputs (one of them is enabled by default) which call the function to change the *form.courses* object:

```
<input class="input-radio" type="radio" value="offline" data-ng-model="fields.courseType" name="courseType" ng-change="changeCourseType('offline')">
<input class="input-radio" type="radio" value="pdf" data-ng-model="fields.courseType" name="courseType" ng-change="changeCourseType('pdf')">
```

THE PROBLEM: When page with the form is initially loaded (the default options list) everything works ok. When the radio input is triggered the set of options changes but AngularJS stops seeing the option selected by the user - that is *fields.course* does not changes.

Please help me to solve this problem!

Directive ($apply/$digest already in progress):

```
(function() {
    var m = angular.module('utils');

    m.directive('courses', [function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            priority: 1,
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (attrs.courses) {
                    scope.$watch(attrs.courses, function() {
                        var list = scope.$eval(attrs.courses);
                        $(elm).html('');
                        var catI;
                        var corI;
                        var group;
                        for (catI in list) {
                            group = $('<optgroup>').attr('label', catI);
                            for (corI in list[catI]) {
                                group.append($('<option>')
                                    .val(list[catI][corI].id)
                                    .html(list[catI][corI].title));
                            }
                            $(elm).append(group);
                        }
                        $(elm).trigger('refresh'); // for jQuery Form Styler
                        $(elm).val(ngModel.$viewValue);
                    }, true);
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: After all I think this issue relates to interaction AngularJS + jQuery + jQuery Form Styler. It is best to create an options set using ng-options, but i need jQuery Form Styler...

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.$apply();` before trigger.

Comment: In the derective 'courses' after ```$(elm).trigger('refresh');```?
If I do this, I get the error: "Action Already In Progress". 
I cant put $apply() in the derective or controller - it already running there...